# Jsoup get generic text

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

Probably stupid question, but I need a simple way to find a string in an html page using Jsoup.

For example I need a simple way to find `Capocchia` on my document.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").execute();

String myString = doc.parse;
```

And then? what I should use? I don't know in which selector my text will be, it could be in `a`,`p`,`span`,`div` and other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple:

```
Document page = Jsoup.connect("http://www.zomato.com/mumbai/starbucks-coffee-fort").get();

boolean containsCapocchia = page.text().contains("Capocchia");

System.out.println(containsCapocchia);
```

For this page result is `false` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well that is a rather difficult question to answer! If you don't know, we can't know either. If you're looking for a generic answer to "get whatever I need from wherever I need" I'm afraid it isn't that simple.

You could always try and look [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for the selector documentation, or you can upgrade that answer's description